# Parallel processing a dataframe after grouping and splitting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has about 5000000 rows. I am doing an operation using a custom function and calling it using apply. Since, the no of rows are huge apply function is extremely slow.
I would like to parallelize this, but the issue is the operation I perform takes each users complete data at a time (i.e grouped by email), hence I need to divide my dataframe such that there is no same email across multiple processes.

How to do this using python Multiprocessing library?

NOTE: avoiding the custom function is not possible , so would appreciate answers on parallelize part

Comment: Have you checked out moodin? https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I used to write my custom function, but I found a very good package [pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel), which does the exact thing with a simple API.

After installing, you need to import it

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()
```

Then simply replace your `apply` with `parallel_apply`.

```
df.parallel_apply(your_function)
```

There are also fancy progress bars, which is always nice to have.

EDIT: Here's my multiprocessing function I used a while ago.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def parallelize_df(df, func):
    '''parallelizes operations on a dataframe by splitting it to chunks. Takes half of your cpu cores.
    '''
    partitions = cpu_count()//2
    df_split = np.array_split(df, partitions)
    pool = Pool(partitions)
    results = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results
```

Here's how you'd use it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rnd = np.random.RandomState(12345)
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rnd.uniform( size=(1000, 4)))


def my_func(df):
    '''Example function'''
    df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: str(x) + 'A')
    df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: str(x) + 'B')
    df[2] = df[2].apply(lambda x: str(x) + 'C')
    df[3] = df[3].apply(lambda x: str(x) + 'D')
    return df

parallelize_df(df, my_func)
```

However, in this example, directly applying function as `my_func(df)` is faster than the parallelized version above because you'd have to open and close pools. You want to parallelize ONLY if your function is really slow and the time taken to open and close pools is insignificant compared to the function execution.

Comment: Hey, thanks.My senior asked me to try using python Multiprocessing library. Can we achieve the same with that?? Also I assume pandarallel is a third party library right?

Comment: Yes, pandarallel is a third party library. I added my function for parallelization above, which uses just the `multiprocessing` module of python.